# JQuery / Javascript - Doc Ready function relates to last loaded Script File / Load order ? - Newbie Question

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views, document-ready

I'm just beginning with Jquery / Javascript so hopefully this wont incur too much wrath from the "how do you not not that groups" :-)

I've been trying out various Jquery add-ins etc that I've seen on the web and trying to  implement them as per their demo's as found on the web.

I have been using these test / samples within the std Visual Studio MVC web templates etc.

I've come across some strange behaviour which is the reason I'm posting this question.

In most of the samples on the web they reference a number of additional scripts which need to be loaded to support the add in - for example I have been using a simple grid which has it's own js file so that needs to be loaded in the page.

Most if not all of these samples then use the Document Ready event / function to then populate the sample with data.

in some of the samples i've used these have not worked and it appears to be a combination of the MVC template telling the page to load scripts in the footer and the Document Ready function / event looking for a function in A JS file that it cant find.

I've made it work by hacking / re-arranging the MVC template to now load the footer scripts in the header of the page.

So the question / questions are.

Does Document Ready run in the context of the last loaded script ?
How does one load a script and give it a alias ? Is it possible to treat these scripts similar to the C# model by using something akin to a using alias ??

and then address the function as ALIASXXX.createsampledata()

as an additional question This I can see can cause problems with master page / partial pages if those pages need different scripts and or scripts have same function names.

Apologies it this question should have been called "how on earth does JQuery work?"

perhaps a bit more explanation ? 
in scenario 1: Std Template MVC header
- Load scripts 1,2,3 
new page - Load add in script
 in document ready - $('#mytable').createTable(dataw, {});
 footer - Load more scripts

The result is error CreateTable not found etc

in scenario 2: Revised header 
- Load scripts 1,2,3 and moved footer scripts
 new page - Load add in script 
in document ready - $('#mytable').createTable(dataw, {});

Result = OK load order makes difference

Answer (score 0):

https://api.jquery.com/ready/

According to the documentation, the document's ready fires when the DOM is ready, rather than scripts, meaning that it has been the case that some handlers bound after that will not fire as the document.ready happened before they were listening. However they do also say that as of JQuery 3, .ready( handler ) will fire if DOMContentLoaded has already happened.

Create grid with .ready() handler

Put stuff in grid with function call at end of that handler

????

Profit

TL;DR

$(document).on( "ready", handler ) is deprecated, 
$( document ).ready( handler ) is recommended.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for replying, I have updated the original question to add a more detailed example as I'm still in the dark :-)